# Convergence test for series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+(-1)^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What would be the approach to resolve whether this series converges (absolutely or conditionally) or diverges?

Comment: For $n=1$ you have that $1+(-1)^1=0$ so the series should start from $n=2$

Comment: You're right, updated.

Comment: Hint: Alternating theorem. Second hint: compare with $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Alternating series test or theorem states that if $a_n$ positive, decreases  and converges to $0$  then $\sum(-1)^na_n<\infty$. In the Q? $a_n$ not decreases.

Comment: @mwomath Can you prove that $a_n$ does not decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirichlet's test states that: if $a_n,b_2$ sequences of real numbers satisfy that:

1- $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$

2- $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$

3- $\left|\sum^{N}_{n=1}b_n\right|\leq M$ for every positive integer $N$

where $M$ is some constant, then the series

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n b_n$ converges.

Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=
\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n }}{{\sqrt {1 + {\textstyle{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \over n}}} }}$.

Clearly, the conditions on $a_n$ is satisfied and there exists $M>0$
s.t.
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 2}^N {b_n } } \right| = \left| {\sum\limits_{n = 2}^N {\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n }}{{\sqrt {1 + {\textstyle{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \over n}}} }}} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N {\frac{{\left| {\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \right|}}{{\left| {\sqrt {1 + {\textstyle{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \over n}}} } \right|}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {\textstyle{{\left( { - 1} \right)^n } \over n}}} }}}  \le M
$$
(choose e.g. $M\ge 100$ or anything $\,\,\ge 2$)

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=2}^N b_n$ isn't bounded simply because the series $\sum b_n$ is divergent.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally flawed for the reason given by @user296113. In fact $\sum_{n=2}^N b_n \sim -\log\sqrt{N}$ as $N \to \infty$, so there cannot possibly be such an $M$ (which must be independent of $N$ for the conclusion to hold).

Answer (score 4):

Denote $\sum a_n$ the given series. We have

$$\vert a_n\vert\ge\frac{1}{n+1}$$
so $\sum a_n$ isn't absolutely convergent. Moreover
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^{-1/2}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
so $\sum a_n$ is convergent as sum of two convergent series.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1} \sqrt { n+1 +(-1)^{n+1}} } \le \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}\sqrt n} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt {n}\sqrt { n +(-1)^n }}.$$

Comment: Could you please show how to proceed?

Comment: The terms $\to 0.$ The above shows the terms are decreasing in absolute value. Apply the alternating series test.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks. But do I also have to prove that the terms are decreasing by taking the first derivative?

Comment: I just showed the terms are decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$ denote the sequence of partial sums and $a_n$ denote the general term of the series. Then, $S_n \to 0$: notice that $a_{2n} = - a_{2n + 1}$ for all $n \ge 1$. So,

$$S_{2n} = \sum_{k=2}^{2n} a_k = a_2 - a_2 + a_4 - a_4 + ... + a_{2n- 2} - a_{2n - 2} + a_{2n} = a_{2n} \to 0$$

$$S_{2n + 1} = \ldots = 0 \to 0$$

(if a sequence $(x_n)$ is such that the subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n + 1})$ converge to the same number, then $(x_n)$ converges to that number)